# Unable to find a specification for `YogaKit (~> 1.18)` depended upon by `FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin`

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, fbflipper

Here I'm facing issue while trying to integrate [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) in my project. Followed the instructions given by [getting started guide](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started.html#ios). End up facing issue `[!] Unable to find a specification for FlipperKit (~> 0.30.0)` while running `pod install`

I tried an alternative way of getting FlipperKit by grabbing it via `git:URL` and point to `branch:master` as followed:

```
pod 'FlipperKit', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git', :branch => 'master', :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git', :branch => 'master', :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git', :branch => 'master', :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git', :branch => 'master', :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', :git => 'https://github.com/facebook/flipper.git', :branch => 'master', :configuration => 'Debug'
```

However I was stopped by another issue `[!] Unable to find a specification for YogaKit (~> 1.18)depended upon byFlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin`. Though I try to get YogatKit withe similar approach (pointing to it's git + branch), I'll continue face another missing dependency issue. Am I missing anything steps here?

I have also raised the [issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/696), feel free to follow up.

I'm on the following environment:

**Flipper Desktop Version:** 0.30.0

**React Native Info:**

```
System:
    OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6360U CPU @ 2.00GHz
    Memory: 495.95 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.19.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
      Android NDK: 19.2.5345600
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
    Xcode: 11.2.1/11B500 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.0 => 0.61.0 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Comment: Might need a `pod install --repo-update`

Comment: Hi Paul, I have tried this prior to your comment but it didn't help. It was showing message that I might have typo in it, but I don't find any. As soon as I remove the bunch of Flipper code my `pod install` works!